# TypeScript - Conditional function arity based on generic type

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to define a function that determines whether an argument is required based on a generic type. I guess this might be called "conditional arity".

```
// I want the function to expect no arguments if the generic type is never
foo<never>();

// This would complain that zero arguments are expected
foo<never>(4);

// These would work based on a non-never type
foo<number>(4);
foo<string>('bar');
```

Answer (score 3):

In TypeScript, the usual way to enforce type-dependent constraints for function arguments or return type is by using overload function declarations:

```
function foo<T extends never>();
function foo<T>(a: T);
function foo<T>(a?: T) {
   // ... implementation
}

// This is ok
foo<never>();

// This is not ok
foo<never>(4); // Argument of type '4' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

// as well as this
foo<number>(); // Type 'number' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'

// These are ok
foo<number>(4);
foo<string>('bar');

// however, nothing prevents the compiler from inferring the type for you
foo(4);
foo();
```